# OnClickListener not working with button on top of google maps fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, onclicklistener

I'm trying to get a button to work on top of a SupportMapFragment but the OnclickListener is not firing.
Here's my code:

MapFragment:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    SP = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    this.SP.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);

    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    ((ViewGroup) view).addView(frameLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    setMapTransparent((ViewGroup) view);
    String mapType = SP.getString("PREF_MAP", "MAP_TYPE_NORMAL");

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();
    if (mapType.equals("MAP_TYPE_NORMAL")) {
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    } else if (mapType.equals("MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE")) {
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    } else if (mapType.equals("MAP_TYPE_HYBRID")) {
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    }
    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    myMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    ((Activity) getActivity()).setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sbutton);
    this.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CLICK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

    return view;
}
```

map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:holo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Main"
 >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sbutton"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"           
    android:background="@drawable/ic_social_share_light"
         />
```

Don't know why's not working.
Can someone please take a look at the code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is you have posted a lot of unrelated code. If you want some help, provide SSCCE.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.
I've added onClick to the button on my map.xml and instead of using the code in MapFragment I used the code in my MapActivity like shown below.
This way my button is working ok.

Map.xml

```
android:onClick="sButton"
```

MapActivity

```
public void sButton(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "CLICK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Great find Mr. Bond! Thank you very much! Any idea why the onclicklistener does not work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You are addind a framelayout on top. Remove this:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    ((ViewGroup) view).addView(frameLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

setMapTransparent((ViewGroup) view);
```

Comment: That souldn't be reason but try with removing setMapTransparent.

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried with removing click and longclick listeners from your map?